# Refresh a Form and all its children

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working on old code that someone else wrote. In this, a subclass of `Windows.Forms.Form` is created within another main `Windows.Forms.Form`

```
class MainForm : Windows.Forms.Form 
{
    m_subForm = null;

    /* Much more stuff */

    private void createSubForm 
    {
         m_subForm= new SubForm();
         m_subForm.Text = "";
         m_subForm.MdiParent = this;
         m_subForm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
         m_subForm.ControlBox = false;
         m_subForm.Show();
         // There is no comment in the code on why this is done:
         this.Height -= 1;
         this.Height += 1;
    }
}
```

These last two lines puzzle me. They are actually necessary, because if they are omitted, the form within the main form chopped off around the edges. Only once you manually scale the screen does the subform fit into the main form again. If tried to replace the `+=` `-=` hack with:

```
this.Refresh();
```

but that doesn't do the trick. So apparently, this only refreshes the main form but not the subform. How can I correct this without this ugly hack?

Comment: this.PerformLayout() solves that?

Comment: Nope, doesn't do anything either.

Comment: Why last 2 lines required? any code to execute in `SizeChanged` event?

Comment: Why, that's what I wonder too: why are they required and why does it work. The `SizeChanged` event was not reimplemented though, so whatever happens behind the screens there is responsible for the thing to work.

Comment: Nope, I don't think there are any reimplementations of any such methods.

Comment: @Yellow what's is the **magic** of `Height-=1;Height+=1`? I've tried your code and **it does nothing different/special than without using it**.

Comment: That is odd, thanks for taking the effort of trying this out. That probably means that somewhere else in the code something is responsible for this not working. But the problem with working on other people's old code is that it's ploughing through lots of irrelevant things, of course. I'll see if I can filter out the relevant bit.

Answer (score 1):

```
     m_subForm.ControlBox = false;
```

That's illegal for an MDI child form, it must have all the window decoration to work correctly.  And to actually be usable as an MDI child, it is a windowing model that is based on allowing the user to minimize/restore/maximize the child windows.  Dates from the early 1990s when monitors still had very low resolutions so there just wasn't a lot of screen real-estate to display windows.

Winforms however doesn't enforce this MDI requirement.  Tinkering with the Height was a hack to get the window to paint correctly.  Ought to be noticeable from the flicker that produces.

There's just no point to MDI when you always display the child window maximized.  You get the exact same effect, minus having to battle the MDI control bar, by simply swapping a UserControl in and out of the form.  Such a UserControl can also be a Form if you set its [TopLevel property](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7692113/17034) to false.

Comment: While this sounds as a very good answer, I do not fully understand what the conclusion is supposed to be. So you are saying that I shouldn't use my Form-within-Form structure, right? I don't completely understand what the alternative is, though, and how the TopLevel priority relates to this...

Comment: I'm just saying that using MDI is pointless if you always maximize the child window.  Might as well use a UserControl instead.