# How to make C# tab switch between form

Tags: c#, forms, tabs, mainwindow

I want to know if it possible to use tabs (like Google Chrome or many others program) in VS Express 2010 to swap between forms without closing any window.

I know there is the tab control item in the tool box but as far as I know you need to create the tab content in the same form. I'm looking for a way to swap between form like if I put Buttons in the the top of each form (workers, customers, ext) that open the form I clicked and close the one I'm in but not change the main window.

Comment: From what I see in this instruction video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HBgSuUU5IMM) you can create all tabs in a separate form class, so not all in one form.

Comment: use Mdi Forms and maximize each of them in every tab.

Comment: Using forms is pretty hokey, you'll have to carefully control location, size and Z-order.  UserControls are the must more obvious alternative, simply place each on a tab.  If necessary, you can very easily turn a Form into a user control with [this code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7692113/17034).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use MDI parent method. If I understand rightly, this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sqRRuyV-dfU) will help you.

OR

You want it to be in the same window.

1. Add this code `this.IsMdiContainer = true;` to main form.
2. Create new form for every menu or button click.

   ```
   Form1 frm1;
   Form2 frm2;
   Form3 frm3;
   ```
3. Create this function and call  every button click for make to hide all form

   ```
   private void HideForms()
   {
       int frmCount = this.MdiChildren.Count<Form>();
       if (frmCount > 0)
       {
           for (int i = 0; i < frmCount; i++)
           {
                this.MdiChildren[i].Hide();
           }
       }
   }
   ```
4. After that button1, button2,... click event

   ```
   private void button1_clicked(...)
   {
       HideForms();
       if ((frm1 == null) || (frm1.IsDisposed))
           frm1 = new Form1();
       frm1.MdiParent = this;
       frm1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
       frm1.Show();
       frm1.BringToFront();
   }
   ```

Comment: MDI parent method open the form in a new window i want it to be in the same window

Comment: thanks, do you know what do i need to add to this code to change the button color when it clicked until other button clicked