# C#, WinForm in another winform

Tags: c#, winforms

I need help. I have winform, like one which is shown on picture, so I want to improve next things, when I click on first button, on the right side will be showed content from another winform, is this possible? I don't want to use panels.

[image]

Comment: You talking about `MDI FORM`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7691468/can-i-host-a-windows-form-inside-a-control/7692113#7692113

Comment: _I don't want to use panels_ Why? What do you want to use?

Comment: Because, it will be messy. For example, I have 10 buttons on left side, and every button has another content, so for every button I have to create one panel, and edit them.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just embed a single `UserControl` dynamically to represent the current *page* or if you want to do everything at design-time - a custom `TabControl`?

> showed content from another winform

You generally don't embed a popup window into another, rather controls.   Otherwise you have to deal with hiding **Minimise, Maximise, Close** etc.

Comment: i'm trying to implement tab control, but I can't hide navigation bar

Comment: Use a UserControl as recommanded. It works quite well and it is not hard to manage the pages yourself. Usually, I would only kept the current page available. Alternatively, you can use third-party component that has tab controls that allows to hide the tab bar.

Answer (score 1):

MDI Form is the best solution for you.

> Use: this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;`
>   to make your child Forms more beautiful in your project!
>
> If you want the MDI parent to auto-size the child form you can code like this.

Code Example:

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IsMdiContainer = true;
    }

    private void btnHotel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
        frm2.Show();
        frm2.MdiParent = this;
    }

    private void btnCaffe_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form3 frm3 = new Form3();
        frm3.Show();
        frm3.MdiParent = this;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use TabControl control -> for each specific content you want to display you just have to add a TabPage to TabControl and when a specific menu option is selected, just switch to required TabControl page.

```
myTabControl.SelectedIndex = 1; // for selecting and displaying page with index 1
```

To hide navigation header of myTabControl, set those props (in constructor or in Form_Load event:

```
myTabControl.ItemSize = new Size(0, 1); 
myTabControl.SizeMode = TabSizeMode.Fixed;
```

Then, you have only content of the TabControl page displayed, without navigation header.

Comment: I can't hide navigation header with those props.

Comment: Try to add one more line:
`myTabControl.Appearance = TabAppearance.FlatButtons;`
I am 100% that this works :)

Comment: I set it into Form_Load event, but unfortunately it's still here

Comment: try in different order:
`myTabControl.Appearance = TabAppearance.FlatButtons;`
`myTabControl.SizeMode = TabSizeMode.Fixed;`
`myTabControl.ItemSize = new Size(0, 1);`

Answer (score 0):

First make it's `this.IsMdiContainer = true;` either from **design time** or **run time**.

then at the button's click event place the following code.

```
        childForm frm = new childForm();
        frm.MdiParent = this;    //the current mdi parent form
        frm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
        frm.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

        frm.Show();
```

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eIcvs.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use mdi (multiple-document interface):
when you want a form start inside mainform, use this following code:

```
    Dim hotelForm As New HotelForm()
    HotelForm.MdiParent = Me // Me is your parent form want to open hotelForm inside
    HotelForm.Show()
```

Answer (score 0):

All forms have a property `TopLevel`, by setting this property to false, then you can deal with that form as a control, and add it to a panel control.

See below psuedo code:

```
Form2 newForm = new Form2();
newForm.TopLevel = false;

myPanel.Controls.Add(newForm);
newForm.Show();
```

After that, your main form design should look like as a navigation control and a panel beside it docked "Fill", then on clicking any navigation button, just create the desired form and set `TopLevel` to false, then show it on the panel

Answer (score 0):

You have to put a Container control like a panel "pnlHost" in your form  and use this for showing any form you want in it

```
    private Form _currentForme;
    private void ShowForm(Form frm)
    {
        _currentForme?.Close();
        _currentForme = null;
        _currentForme = frm;
        _currentForme.TopLevel = false;
        _currentForme.TopMost = false;
        pnlHost.Controls.Clear();
        _currentForme.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
        pnlHost.Controls.Add(_currentForme);
        _currentForme.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        _currentForme.Show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use MDI parent and child for this.

But I guess you could also finish the child application, build the exe and initiate it as a new process from your Parent application.
Check the solution given [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/94a67da1-8143-4e37-86c0-4deab0d1ec93/c-run-exe-from-a-form-and-keep-the-exe-within-the-boundaries-of-that-original-form?forum=winforms).
I tried a similar approach long ago and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score -1):

Set current form as a MdiParent then use Datagridview to display data from other forms